# How to solve "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AbortedError : RecvTensor expects a different device incarnation" in Tensorflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow

I am trying to distribute a simple Tensorflow computation into two machines in Amazon AWS.

I am running the following program with the command line argument 0 and 1 in machine 1 and machine 2, respectively. I am getting the following error: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AbortedError : RecvTensor expects a different device incarnation...Your worker job ... was probably restarted. Check your worker job for the reason why it was restarted`. However, I haven't restarted the Machine 2.

I used `ping` and `nc` to make sure that Machine 2 is indeed listening in the designated port.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import sys

config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
task_number = int(sys.argv[1])
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"local": ["localhost:2222", "<private_ip_of_machine_2>:2222"]})
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="local", task_index=task_number, config=config, start=True)

print("Starting server #{}".format(task_number))

tf.reset_default_graph()


r = 2
c = 2

if task_number == 0:
    with tf.device('/job:local/task:0'):
        v = tf.Variable(np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(r, c)), name="v")

    with tf.device('/job:local/task:1'):
        w = tf.matmul(v, v, name="w")

    with tf.device('/job:local/task:0'):
        sum = tf.reduce_sum(w, name="sum")


    sess = tf.Session("grpc://localhost:2222")
    print("Session Run Start")
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print("Res: ", sess.run(sum))

    LOGDIR = "./tf_board_square/"
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR, sess.graph)
#writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

else:
    server.join()
```

The program works in localhost with the tasks running in different ports.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the cluster specification was incorrectly defined. Instead of `localhost`, I had to specify the IP address of Machine 1 in the spec. Otherwise, Machine 2 has no way to know the address of Machine 1. Hence, I believe, each tf server needs to know the address of all the other servers.

`cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"local": ["ip_of_machine_2:2222", "<ip_of_machine_2>:2222"]})`